# Help first time making cookies

Tags: baking

I went to the supermarket to buy the sugar cookie dough already in sheet form but didn't find it can we use pie crust to make cookies

Comment: I really don't know why you'd want to. In order to make pie crust palatable as cookies, you'd have doctor it up to the point that it would be easier to just make a simple cookie recipe from scratch. For example, look at this recipe for [Peanut Butter Cookies](http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Best-Peanut-Butter-Cookies-Ever/Detail.aspx?prop24=hn_slide1_Best-Peanut-Butter-Cookies-Ever&evt19=1). That's pretty darn easy, and if you have any questions about it (or any other cookie recipe), we can help.

Comment: Agreed. Not sure why pie crust comes to mind, unless you just happen to have it on hand. It would be easier to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use pie crust to make cookies. You will have to roll it out and cut out cookies from it. The result is called "shortbread cookies". Its taste and texture is quite different from a "standard" American cookie.

If you use unsweetened pie crust, you will probably want to add something sweet on top of your shortbread cookies. The simplest thing is to dust them with lots of icing sugar the moment they come out of the oven.

If you want a "standard" cookie, you'll have to use real cookie dough, storebought or made from scratch.